# Facebook doesn't like our SSL Certificate

Tags: facebook, ssl, certificate

We have a wildcard SSL certificate for our domains.  If I setup the Secure Canvas URL, we get the dreaded empty response error.  My understanding is that this is because Facebook has a problem with our SSL cert.

Is there any recommendations on how to figure out what is wrong with our SSL certificate?

I read this blog post: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/567/

I ran the test on the site they recommended, it looks pretty good to me.  Could that Beast mode warning be causing this problem?  Here are the results I get back:

Certificate Information
Common names    *.mydomain.com
Alternative names    *.mydomain.com mydomain.com
Prefix handling Not required for subdomains
Valid from  Tue Jul 19 00:00:00 UTC 2011
Valid until Wed Jul 18 23:59:59 UTC 2012 (expires in 8 months and 18 days)
Key  RSA / 2048 bits
Signature algorithm SHA1withRSA
Server Gated Cryptography    Netscape Step-Up, Microsoft Server Gated Cryptography
Weak key (Debian)    No
Issuer  EssentialSSL CA
Next Issuer     COMODO Certification Authority   TRUSTED
Chain length (size) 2 (2581 bytes)
Chain issues    None
Validation type  Domain-validated (DV)
Revocation information   CRL, OCSP
Revocation status   Good (not revoked)
Trusted Yes

Protocols
TLS 1.2  No
TLS 1.1  No
TLS 1.0  Yes
SSL 3.0 Yes
SSL 2.0+ upgrade support     Yes
SSL 2.0 Yes N
(*) N next to protocol version means the protocol has no cipher suites enabled

Cipher Suites (sorted by strength; server has no preference)
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x4)  128
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x5)  128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f) 128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x33)   DH 1024 bits (p: 128, g: 1, Ys: 128)  128
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xa) 168
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x16)    168
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35) 256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x39)   DH 1024 bits (p: 128, g: 1, Ys: 128)  256

Miscellaneous
Test date   Thu Nov 03 19:37:27 UTC 2011
Test duration   55.590 seconds
Server signature     Apache
Server hostname  dev.mydomain.com
Session resumption  Yes
BEAST attack    Vulnerable   INSECURE (more info)
Secure Renegotiation    Supported, with client-initiated renegotiation disabled
Insecure Renegotiation  Not supported
Strict Transport Security   No
TLS version tolerance    0x0304: 0x301; 0x0399: 0x301; 0x0499: fail
PCI compliant    No
FIPS-ready   No
Ephemeral DH    1024 bits (p: 128, g: 1, Ys: 128)

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the intermediate certificates? Check at http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html to see if you have a full chain

Also good is the checker at https://www.ssllabs.com/

If the app is FBML Facebook is very strict about which certificates it will accept when connecting to your site to download the content - if your app uses iFrames it's mostly up to the user's browser settings and you'll get away with less strict checking

The quote from that blog post which seems to have tripped up most FBML apps is:

> If you enable SSL for your FBML app, please make sure that your SSL certificate includes all intermediate certificates in the chain of trust as our SSL validation is strict. You can use third-party SSL analysis tools (e.g., https://www.ssllabs.com/index.html) to check your certificate status and fix any errors (and warnings). If your SSL certificate has problems, you may see "Empty response received" error when you load your FBML canvas app.